# SCNKit: Hit test doesn't hit node's dynamically modified geometry

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, metal

I'm facing an issue where [`SCNView.hitTest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest) does not detect hits against geometry that I'm modifying dynamically on the cpu.

Here's the overview: I have a node that uses an `SCNGeometry` created from a `MTLBuffer` of vertices:

```swift
func createGeometry(vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer, vertexCount: Int) -> SCNGeometry {
    let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [
        SCNGeometrySource.init(
            buffer: vertexBuffer,
            vertexFormat: .float3,
            semantic: .vertex,
            vertexCount: vertexCount,
            dataOffset: 0,
            dataStride: MemoryLayout<SIMD3<Float>>.stride),
    ], elements: [
        SCNGeometryElement(indices: ..., primitiveType: .triangles)
    ])
}


let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer = // shared buffer
let vertexCount = ...

let node = SCNNode(geometry: createGeometry(vertexBuffer: vertexBuffer, vertexCount: vertexCount))
```

As the app is running, I then dynamically modify the vertex buffer in the SceneKit update loop:

```swift
// In SceneKit update function

var ptr = vertexBuffer.contents().bindMemory(to: SIMD3<Float>.self, capacity: vertexCount)

for i in 0..<vertexCount {
    ptr[i] = // modify vertex
}
```

This dynamic geometry is correctly rendered by SceneKit. However when I then try hit testing against `node` using [`SCNView.hitTest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest), no hits are detected against the modified geometry.

I can work around this by re-creating the node's geometry after modifying the data:

```swift
// after updating data
node.geometry = createGeometry(vertexBuffer: vertexBuffer, vertexCount: vertexCount)
```

However this feels like a hack.

What is the proper way to have hit testing work reliably for a node with dynamically changing `SCNGeometry`?

Comment: I dont know, if this I want to say goes in the right direction, but it is possible that this is similar issue as i.Ex. when you use a Animated Character, I read some time ago, that the Deformation of the Body is only performed by the GPU and the Data that can be hit-tested is in effect always the original Data (usually the T-Position Model of a human kind character), instead of the modifyed one. Maybe your issue is related.

Comment: There are some interesting suggestions in this thread that may be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/91618
(creating new SCNGeometry performance is just fine / use SCNMorpher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a hit-test search, SceneKit looks for **SCNGeometry** objects along the ray you specify. For each intersection between the ray and a geometry, SceneKit creates a hit-test result to provide information about both the SCNNode object containing the geometry and the location of the intersection on the geometry’s surface.

The problem in your case is that when you modify the buffer’s contents (**MTLBuffer**) at render time, SceneKit does not know about it, and therefore cannot update SCNGeometry object which is used for performing hit-test.

So the only way I can see to solve this issue is to recreate your **SCNGeometry** object.

Comment: I more or less understand why it doesn't work today. The question is: recreating SCNGeometry instances is somewhat expensive, so is there a better way to let SceneKit know that the geometry has changed so it can update whatever data structures it uses for hit testing?

Comment: @MattBierner unfortunately there isn't any better way than recreating your SCNGeometry object.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no `proper way` to make hit-testing work reliably in your situation. It would apparently be possible if it didn't depend on the `SceneKit`/`Metal` render loop and delegate pattern. But since it entirely depends on them, this is an unrealistically expensive operation to recreate SCNGeometry's instances, as you said earlier. So, I totally agree with @HamidYusifli.